# How to separate nested comma separated column values in pandas data frame using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like below

**df Creation**

```
df= pd.read_csv("dump12.csv")
df=df[['ID','linkedShipments','Status']]

df.dtypes()
ID                 object
linkedShipments    object
Status             object
```

**df (Input Data)**

```
ID Status     linkedShipments
12  Active   [{'SID': 'GBDXY551', 'Code': 'GBDXY55', 'Num': '2021121'}, {'SID': 'GBDXY551', 'Code': 'GBDXY55', 'Num': '20211215'}]
32  Expired  [{'SID': 'CHSGI422', 'Code': 'CHSGI421', 'Num': '4024421'}, {'SID': 'GBDXY551', 'Code': 'GBDXY55', 'Num': '20211222'}]
36  Expired  [{'SID': 'CHSGI428', 'Code': 'CHSGI907', 'Num': '4024568'}, {'SID': 'GBDXY556', 'Code': 'GBDXY55', 'Num': '20211333'}]
```

**Expected Output**

```
ID  SID         Code     Num      Status
12  GBDXY551    GBDXY55  2021121  Active
12  GBDXY551    GBDXY55  20211215 Active
32  CHSGI422    CHSGI421 4024421  Expired
32  GBDXY551    GBDXY55  20211222 Expired
36  CHSGI428    CHSGI907 4024568  Expired
36  GBDXY556    GBDXY55  20211333 Expired

**My Current Code**
```

This works only with one Key and I also want add  Status Column to output data frame how can that be done.

```
#load as dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_data = {} #define new data
#treverse all rows in current data
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #json only accept double quotes, so convert singal quotes to double quotes
    shipment_dict_list = json.loads(row['linkedShipments'].replace("\'", "\"")) 
    for shipment_dict in shipment_dict_list:
        new_data.setdefault("ID",[]).append(row['ID'])
        for key in shipment_dict:
            new_data.setdefault(key,[]).append(shipment_dict[key])
print(pd.DataFrame(new_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a combination of `explode` and `apply(pd.Series)`:

```
df2 = df.explode('linkedShipments').reset_index(drop = True)
df2.join(df2['linkedShipments'].apply(pd.Series)).drop(columns = 'linkedShipments')
```

output:

```
    ID  Status  SID         Code        Num
0   12  Active  GBDXY551    GBDXY55     2021121
1   12  Active  GBDXY551    GBDXY55     20211215
2   32  Expired CHSGI422    CHSGI421    4024421
3   32  Expired GBDXY551    GBDXY55     20211222
4   36  Expired CHSGI428    CHSGI907    4024568
5   36  Expired GBDXY556    GBDXY55     20211333
```

### Edit

I constructed the df as such

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ID', 'Status', 'linkedShipments'], data = [
  [12,'Active',   [{'SID': 'GBDXY551', 'Code': 'GBDXY55', 'Num': '2021121'}, {'SID': 'GBDXY551', 'Code': 'GBDXY55', 'Num': '20211215'}]],
  [32,'Expired',  [{'SID': 'CHSGI422', 'Code': 'CHSGI421', 'Num': '4024421'}, {'SID': 'GBDXY551', 'Code': 'GBDXY55', 'Num': '20211222'}]],
  [36,'Expired',  [{'SID': 'CHSGI428', 'Code': 'CHSGI907', 'Num': '4024568'}, {'SID': 'GBDXY556', 'Code': 'GBDXY55', 'Num': '20211333'}]],
]
)
```

Comment: Not working as expected. It not exploding

Comment: @pankaj I have added a construction of your df since you did not provide one -- is the solution working in this case? If so please update your answer with how you are creating your df so we cxan see why it is not working

Comment: @piterberg, I used your construction, It worked . while I am using my data frame it doesn't work. I have added how I creating my dataframe `df` in the question

Comment: @piterberg, When I use your code on the on my dataframe, its not exploding

Comment: @pankaj I need "dump12.csv" to be able to run your code, pls post